# How can use ssh to connect to my university network over VPN

Tags: mac, terminal, ssh, unix

I am still a beginner with using terminal. I am trying to ssh from my mac at home to a linux at my university. I am using VPN to connect to the network. When I ping the IP address of the computer I want to connect to it responds. I can connect when I am on campus, but not when I'm off. When I try `ssh -v username@IP` this is what I get:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.36.0.250 [10.36.0.250] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.36.0.250 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.36.0.250 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Running traceroute gives

```
traceroute to 10.36.0.250 (10.36.0.250), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  host141-129.vpnhosts.csulb.edu (134.139.141.129)  30.269 ms  29.085 ms  27.597 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would contact the IT support team of the university with this information, they might be in a better position to analyze this.

Comment: it looks like your University blocks many Ports. Maybe you have a wrong IP Adress, but you can't definitly not reach the 22 Port - also ICMP is turned off, so your traceroute will not work too.

Comment: The IP address 10.x.x.x is a local address only ands so not accessable from the internet just your campus. Ask your system admin how to access off the campus

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I did I was being denied access, so I spoke to IT at school and got access. Thank you everyone for your help.